# Maven: Failed to resolve dependency: C:\Program Files\Java\lib\tools.jar

Tags: eclipse, maven, tools.jar

I'm trying to use the cargo plugin to run a web application in a local Jetty container from inside Eclipse. This seems to be working for other people with the exact same pom.xml, but I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.0.3:start (default-cli) on project wsc: Failed to resolve dependency: C:\Program Files\Java\lib\tools.jar -> [Help 1]
```

How do I resolve this? The project is set to use jdk1.7.0 as the "JRE System Library". I am starting Eclipse with "-vm " and even JAVA_HOME is set to the JDK path.

Any ideas? I've been researching on this for a while and getting crazy about that. The documentation on [including tools.jar as dependency](https://maven.apache.org/general.html#tools-jar-dependency) didn't help me.

**Important:** This seems to work outside Eclipse, e.g. with `mvn -P local cargo:start`.

---

Program output when started from Eclipse:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Web Services Computing 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- cargo-maven2-plugin:1.0.3:start (default-cli) @ wsc ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.324s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Oct 22 19:10:18 CEST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/107M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.0.3:start (default-cli) on project wsc: Failed to resolve dependency: C:\Program Files\Java\lib\tools.jar -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

---

Dependency tree output (also started from Eclipse):

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ wsc ---
[INFO] de.tum.ibis.wsc:wsc:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO] \- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'inside eclipse'? m2e? Something else?

Comment: Show us the output of `mvn dependency:tree` - maybe that will bring some light. Or any ideas from `mvn -X -P local cargo:start` output?

Comment: @bmargulies: Yes, using a m2e run configuration.

Comment: @dma_k: I'll edit and include also the program output, but there's nothing interesting there.

Comment: Interesting. Same version of maven inside and out? Same global settings?

Comment: Yes, using the Maven binary on my PATH. Nothing changed there.

Comment: Notwithstanding it working from command-line, is `tools.jar` indeed present in `C:\Program Files\Java\lib` folder?  Typically jdk gets installed in a subfolder of `C:\Program Files\Java`.

Comment: @Raghuram: No, it's not there. I have jdk1.7.0 and jre7 installed there as subfolders.

Comment: It looks like Eclipse redefines `JAVA_HOME` (or sets `java.home` system variable), but they are pointing to wrong location.

Answer (score 1):

You have to start eclipse with a jdk instead of a jre.
If you edit your eclipse.ini and put a jdk to the vm arguments it should work.

`-vm`

`C:/java_1_6/jdk/bin/javaw.exe`